# Are Java enums considered primitive or reference types?

Tags: java

If I have an enum object, is it considered a primitive or a reference?

Comment: Enums are absolutely normal classes w/ some optimizations (for serialization) + c-tor check for inheritance level + extra shared array (non cloned()) of declared enums. The public method values() always returns a new copy. They can implement interfaces and what not :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's a reference type. Java primitives are `boolean byte short char int long float double`.

You can get the enumeration constant's value by calling `ordinal()`, [which is used by EnumSet and EnumMap `iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--) and "traverses the elements in their natural order (the order in which the enum constants are declared)"

You can even add your own members to the enum class, like this:

```
public enum Operation {
  PLUS   { double eval(double x, double y) { return x + y; } },
  MINUS  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x - y; } },
  TIMES  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x * y; } },
  DIVIDE { double eval(double x, double y) { return x / y; } };

  // Do arithmetic op represented by this constant
  abstract double eval(double x, double y);
}
//Elsewhere:
Operation op = Operation.PLUS;
double two = op.eval(1, 1);
```

Comment: +1 I was completely unaware of this functionality. Could you provide an example of how to use that operation in action?

Comment: `enum` instances don't have to be immutable actually. An enum can have mutable variables.

Comment: @SLaks: Be that as it may, it is still inaccurate to say "Java enums are immutable object instances" just because you feel they *should* be.

Comment: @Slaks that's pretty cool. That means you could store the operation and simply `getOperation().eval(getA(),getB())` without a switch/case. I like! :-)

Comment: @glowcoder It's basically an implementation of the Strategy pattern using an enum. You could achieve the same by declaring a Strategy interface and derive classes from this interface, implementing concrete strategies. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern for further details.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to say that "Java enums are immutable object references."

Answer (score 14):

The way enums work is actually not too different from how they were used before their introduction with Java 5:

```
public final class Suit {

public static final Suit CLUBS = new Suit();
public static final Suit DIAMONDS = new Suit();
public static final Suit HEARTS = new Suit();
public static final Suit SPADES = new Suit();

/**
 * Prevent external instantiation.
 */
private Suit() {
    // No implementation
}}
```

By instantiating the different suits on class loading it is ensured that these will be mutually exclusive and the private constructor ensures that no further instances will be created.

These would be comparable either through == or equals.

The Java 5 enum works pretty much the same way, but with some necessary features to support serialization etc.

I hope this background sheds some further light.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2007/java/making-the-most-of-java-50-enum-tricks) essentially shows you how enums are implemented, and as SLaks says, they are references.

Answer (score -2):

Enums are reference types, in that they can have methods and can be executed from command line as well , if they have main method.

See following "Planet" example from Sun/Oracle

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html