# Not all cases appear to be covered by switch on enum

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have [a big amount of code that distills down to] this:

```
class Test {
    enum Bool { False, True };

    static boolean decode(Bool input) {
        boolean b;
        switch (input) {
            case False: b = false; break;
            case True:  b = true;  break;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

`javac` rejects it on the grounds that:

```
Main.java:11: error: variable b might not have been initialized
    return b;
```

I'm a bit confused.  I thought the point of `enum`s was to have the values list pinned down at compile-time.  In what case might my variable `b` not have been initialized?

Comment: It is possible for someone to change the `Test$Bool.class` file after compiling and before running the program, and therefore sneak in another enum value.

Comment: The compiler does not consider the branches of switch statements exhaustive unless there is a default clause. Switches on enums are not exempt from this. Just as if you wrote a series of `if/else if` statements, they wouldn't be exhaustive unless you had a final bare `else` clause.

Comment: @khelwood: as unsatisfying as it is, I'd accept that if it were an answer.

Comment: @JB. Fair enough. Answer posted.

Comment: Instead of assigning the value in the default branch I'd suggest to throw an `IllegalStateException`. If you ever add another value to your enum you'll be able to find the error faster (if you forgot to edit your switch-Statements) (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019562/what-is-the-usage-of-default-when-the-switch-is-for-an-enum )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not consider the branches of switch statements exhaustive unless there is a default clause. Switches on enums are not exempt from this. Just as if you wrote a series of `if`/`else if` statements, they wouldn't be exhaustive unless you had a final bare `else` clause, even if the conditions you were checking were logically complementary.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it is possible that `input` is null. Then, the switch case won't initialize it. A fix is to make a `default` section incase it is null.

```
static boolean decode(Bool input) {
    boolean b;
    switch (input) {
        case False: b = false; break;
        case True:  b = true;  break;
        default: b = false; // you can make it true too.
    }
    return b;
}
```

Since I didn't test it, I don't know if it compiles. if not, just initialize `b` in the beginning.

```
static boolean decode(Bool input) {
    boolean b = false;
    switch (input) {
        case False: b = false; break;
        case True:  b = true;  break;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: If it's null, I'd expect it to trigger an NPE on switch (or first compare), but *not* to reach the return.